# Creating output Bokeh-file

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I have tried to replicate the "movies" example found on [Bokeh Movies Example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/movies/main.py) but with other parameters to fit my own needs. New to Bokeh, I can't seem to understand the syntax of actually getting an output file/icon that I can use later on to run the program from.

Basically I'm not sure what `curdoc` is doing by the end of the movies-code, and why there isn't a `output_file("movies.html", title="Movies Tester", mode="cdn")` or alike, somewhere.

If there is a better example of where I can make use of an input pandas DataFrame, whose columns I would like to present in different forms in an interactive plot, at a homepage, it would of course be appreciable as well.

Any tips or tricks that I can make use of is very much welcome!

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Movies example is a bokeh server application. It can only be used by running it with a Bokeh server, i.e. by executing

```
bokeh serve --show movies
```

on the command line. There is no output file to create. To interact with a Bokeh server application, it has to be *run*.

The job of the code inside a Bokeh application is to build up a Bokeh document (i.e. put in plots and widgets, etc) so that is what it is doing with `curdoc().add_root(...)`. The code in the script is building up plots and widgets in a layout, and adding that to a new document. Every time a browser connects to a Bokeh server, the Bokeh server runs the application code to create a new fresh Document for that session.

The `output_file` function, by contrast, is for generating *standalone* HTML/JS that does *not rely on the Bokeh server*. (It's still possible to have lots of interactions in standalone documents, with things like `CustomJS` callbacks, you generally just can't run *real Python code*.)

*(It is also possible to "embed" a Bokeh serve as a library in a regular python script, but that's a more advanced usage. See, e.g. the user's guide section [Embedding Bokeh Server as a Library](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library) for more information.)*